# Sending data from chrome extension to SQL database using XAMPP

Tags: javascript, php, sql-server, google-chrome-extension, xampp

I am basically building an extension that gets the url and title of the current tab and sends it to the SQL database at localhost using XAMPP.

This is my code

```
(popup.html)
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello World</title>

    <script src="jquery-3.3.1.min">
    </script>

<script src="popup.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <form action="http://localhost/data.php" method="post">
        <var id="lol">kk</var>
                   First Name: <input type="text" name="name">
        <input type="Submit">
    </form>

</body>

</html> 


(popup.js)
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null,function(tab) {
var tablink = tab.url;
var tabtitle = tab.title;
document.getElementById("lol").textContent=tablink;
document.getElementById("card").textContent=tabtitle;
});

(data.php)
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "uppercase";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect("$servername", "$username", "$password");
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
mysqli_select_db($conn,$database);
$sql = "INSERT INTO urltable (name,url)
VALUES
('$_POST[lol]','$_POST[card]')";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
echo("success");
} else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

I want the url and title of current tab to be saved in database(uppercase).
Even though I have specified the ID for title and url i.e(card and lol respectivesly). Nothing is getting entered in Database if I run my extension.

Comment: Did you check that variables you're sending to your SQL query got expected values ?

Answer (score 0):

You're only sending one variable, named `name`, with this form.

You can send `lol` and `card` values with hidden fields like this :

```
<input type="hidden" id="lol" name="lol" value="" />
<input type="hidden" id="card" name="card" value="" />
```

Remove tag with id `lol` : `<var id="lol">kk</var>`

This way you'll be setting `lol` and `card` values and sending related variable to PHP.

Comment: I tried as you suggested but still nothing is getting stored in my database.